# export gridview rows to excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had task in my project to export grid view rows to excel sheet I serached and I had code and I did it but this class export only current page from grid view so I want also to export all gridview rows.

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class GridViewExportUtil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="gv"></param>
    public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            //  Create a form to contain the grid
            Table table = new Table();

            //  add the header row to the table
            if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
            }

            //  add each of the data rows to the table
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //  add the footer row to the table
            if (gv.FooterRow != null)
            {
                GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
            }

            //  render the table into the htmlwriter
            table.RenderControl(htw);

            //  render the htmlwriter into the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Replace any of the contained controls with literals
/// </summary>
/// <param name="control"></param>
private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        Control current = control.Controls[i];
        if (current is LinkButton)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
        }
        else if (current is ImageButton)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
        }
        else if (current is HyperLink)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
        }
        else if (current is DropDownList)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
        }
        else if (current is CheckBox)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
        }

        if (current.HasControls())
        {
            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current);
        }
    }
}
}
```

CS:

```
 protected void imgbtn_export_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewExportUtil.Export("Problems.xls", this.GridView1);
    }
```

Comment: [1]: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html Matt Berseth explained as pellucid manner.

Comment: I did all code in the link which you sent to me but I didnot make the gridlines to grid where the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Does your gridview apply anything special to the data that is not already in the data source that it is bound to?  If not, I would suggest you export directly from the same dataset that the gridview is bound to, thereby avoiding having to deal with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the full source for the page so I would have to speculate, but based upon the wording of your question I suspect that you have enabled paging within the GridView control and as such the only data available in the GridView.Rows collection will be the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Just Before Exporting make the paging function of the gridview as false, so that all the rows are called on demand.